# Ansible - use loopItem as hash key with an existing variable

Tags: hash, ansible

i work with Ansible 2.4.2.0.

I have a playbook and defined a variable `host: mymachine`. I have a registered variable that looks like:

```
"json": {
    "results": [
    {
      [...],
      "item": "myname",
      "stdout_lines": "abc"
      [...]
    },
    {
      [...],
      "item": "myname2",
      "stdout_lines": "xyz"
      [...]
    {
    ]
}
```

I now want to use the values of `item` as keys of a new hash (together with my `host`).
Something like this task:

```
-name Create Hash
    set_fact:
      "{{ host[item.item] }}": "{{ item.stdout_lines }}"
    with_items:
      - "{{ json.results }}" `
```

I want my hash to look like:

```
"mymachine": {
  "myname": "abc",
  "myname2": "xyz"
 }
```

I know the iteration of `json.results` works and `item.item` and `item.stdout_lines` are accessible. But the `"{{ host[item.item] }}":`-part won't work. I tried all combinations of brackets, I get different error messages, depending on what combination of brackets I use.

Hope someone can tell me the correct syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want my Hash to look like:
>
> ```
> "mymachine": {
>   "myname": "abc",
>   "myname2": "xyz"
> }
> ```

If you want to define a dictionary named `mymachine`, why does your code not even contain the string `mymachine`?

> the `"{{ host[item.item] }}":`-part won't work

Why should it work, if trying to use it is the first occurrence of `host` in your code? You refer to a variable without defining it.

---

Here's correct syntax for what you want to achieve:

```
- name: Create Hash
  set_fact:
    mymachine: "{{ mymachine | default({}) | combine(myelement) }}"
  vars:
    myelement: "{ '{{ item.item }}':'{{ item.stdout_lines }}' }"
  with_items:
    - "{{ json.results }}"
```

Comment: I just wanted to use "mymachine" as name for the hash and thought i could just "add" key/value pairs without initializing it. Thanks for clarifying this. Your example looks great. I can test this on monday and will then mark your answer.